# How to parse webpage one by one while next button is clickable using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I need to parse page one by one while next button is clickable. I'm connecting to the first page by default and parsing up to the last element from this page:

```
  driver.get("https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?country=UA&page=1");
```

I'm getting all elements from the first page page:

```
  WebElement tableId = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));
  List<WebElement> trElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("./tbody/tr"));
```

And finally trying to check if next button is clickable then parse from this current page and other remaining pages if they're exists:

```
        WebElement nextButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@title,'next')]"));

        if(isClickable(nextButton, driver)) {
            for (int id = 1; id <= trElements.size(); id++) {
                for (WebElement element : trElements) {
                    //...
                    id++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            nextButton.click();
        }
```

When I walked through the loop of the current first page - all is fine, but I need to check next button to parse another page again if it's necessary.

`isClickable()` method looks like:

```
public static boolean isClickable(WebElement el, WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is the error?

Comment: @dev, the problem how to realize it correctly. It works only for the first time, but I need to parse over the all pages while next button is clickable.

Comment: `By.xpath("./tbody/tr")` it does not identify anything

Comment: why you iterating all over trElements list? without doing anything... I would suggest just check `if (list.size() == 50)`

Comment: I've updated a bit code with part `By.xpath("./tbody/tr")` to make it sense. `(list.size() == 50)` means as fixed check, but I would like to have dynamic check no matter how many pages next button will have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to [suggestion by Alexey R](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/42635/34920) like:

> After you do element.click(); your DOM gets rebuilt so after that you
>   have your trElements stayed filled with stale elements.

```
        driver.get("https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?country=UA&page=1");
        List<Journal> journalList = new ArrayList<>();

        //...

        for (int i = 0; i < countOfPages; i++) {
            WebElement tableId = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));
            List<WebElement> trElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("./tbody/tr"));

            for (int id = 1; id <= trElements.size(); id++) {
                WebElement element = trElements.get(id);
                String title = element.findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]/a")).getText();
                String country = "Ukraine";
                journalList.add(new Journal(id, title, country));

            }
            WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("(//div[@class='pagination_buttons']/a)[2]");
            element.click();
        }
```

So I put dynamic elements which can be changed per page inside loop to make it work.